# emacs fill-paragraph to consider only the current line and below?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Assume my cursor is at _

```
 This is line 1.
_This is line 2. 
 This is line 3.
```

If I use fill-paragraph (meta-q), emacs transforms the text like this.

```
 This is line 1.  This is line 2.  This is line 3.
```

But instead I expect this.

```
 This is line 1.
 This is line 2.  This is line 3.
```

Currently I have to insert additional blank line before line 2

```
 This is line 1.

_This is line 2. 
 This is line 3.
```

and then invoke fill-paragraph, but it's not very convenient.

Thanks

Comment: what about select a region and then use `M-q`?

Answer (score 1):

Or a simple function if you like

```
(defun fill-following-paragraph ()
  "Do fill-region from the current line to the end of the
buffer"
  (interactive)
  (fill-region (line-beginning-position) (point-max)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good candidate for advice:

```
(defadvice fill-paragraph (around start-filling-at-current-line activate)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (line-beginning-position) (point-max))
    ad-do-it))
```